# Git Adding build directory from subdirectory which is a separate git repo

Tags: git

I have a react application loads into an php application (wordpress). The react application is inside a subdirectory and its a separate git repository.

Now when shipping the product I want only the build directory (/js/app/build) to ship with php app.

The git in master (php app) directory doesn't add the js build directory when I try to add it. What is the correct approach of this?

Directory Structure:

```
php-app
|-- js
    |-- app // git repository
        |-- build
main.php
file2.php
example.php
```

NOTE: `/js/app/build` is ignored in the js app repository but it is needed to be included in php repository.

Comment: please define "shipping the product". Do you use an artifact tracking system for that? Do you release a tag?

Comment: No artifact tracking system is used. I have tag for every release. Want to add the `/js/app/build` directory to the php app VCS.